# Show gridlines on the top of 3D plot in mathematica

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, grid-lines

```
P[n_, m_, x_, y_] := Plot3D[{Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]*(x^2 + y^2)^m*LaguerreL[n, m, (x^2 + y^2)]^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", LabelStyle -> Black,Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> {True, True, True}, AspectRatio -> 1, FaceGrids -> {{{0, 1, 0}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}, {{-1, 0, 0}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}},Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1}}]; P[0, 1, x, y]
```

I want the grid to cover from the top i.e. the top line is missing which doesn't look good.

Comment: @ aman bhatia you mean box or what. be specific please

Comment: With my code, I get a grid but the vertical lines that appeared are not covered with a horizontal line on the top that doesn't look good. I want a horizontal line on top of the vertical lines that appeared in the plot.

Comment: Maybe try tinkering with the `PlotRange` option, like `PlotRange -> {0, 0.31}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working on FaceGrid**

```
P[n_, m_, x_, y_] := 
 Plot3D[{Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]*(x^2 + y^2)^m*
    LaguerreL[n, m, (x^2 + y^2)]^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", LabelStyle -> Black, 
  Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> {True, True, True}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  
  FaceGrids -> {
    {{0, 1, 0}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}, 
    {{-1, 0, 0}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}
    , {{0, 0, 1}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}
    , {{1, 0, 0}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}
    , {{0, 0, -1}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}
    , {{0, -1, 0}, {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[0, 1, 0.1]}}
    },
  
  ImageSize -> 500, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, 
    Automatic, {0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 
     1}}]; P[0, 1, x, y]
```

Finally i hope its solved for you!

[image]

Comment: @ aman bhatia is that what you want friend! Grid lines now everywhere even below!

Comment: Yes, I wanted exactly the same. Thanks a lot @ Alrubaie.